# Adaptive Objective C subclass method names?

Tags: objective-c

I may very well be thinking of something that doesn't exist, but here goes nothing.

A long, long time ago I could have sworn I saw a technique for dynamically naming Objective C methods based on the name of the class itself. As I recall, such was handy in case you had a class that needed to be subclassed and subtly customized many times, it was possible to then generate custom method names for each subclass without actually implementing them manually by hand. This improved readability a lot, since your code was still unified in the superclass, but otherwise automatically customized for the subclasses by the preprocessor or compiler.

I can't remember if this was some whacky macro, or a hidden Objective C keyword, or what. I just recall that I raised eyebrows the first time I saw it, but now I can't seem to locate it again now that I've got a use for it.

At the risk of sounding vague, has anyone heard of anything like this?

Comment: Could this possibly be what you're looking for? Objective C categories?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: Never heard of anything like this

Comment: While this sounds like an interesting piece of code, rather than ask for an obscure, possibly non-existent, tool that may solve the problem you have, why not just ask directly how to solve the problem you have?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't want to maintain what are essentially duplicate methods across 30 or so subclasses. The method names all contain part of the class name in them (for readability), so they need to be customized like that on a per-class basis, even though the code inside them is identical. I could have sworn there was a way to specify method names so they were somehow based on the name of the class implementation, but I can't remember how or where I saw that.